# "Path not found" when using interrupt INT 21h, 3Dh

Tags: assembly, x86

When using interrupt `INT 21h, 3Dh` in my program, the `CF` is set, which means there was an error while trying to open my file. The error code in the `AX` register is `3`: "`path not found"` according to [this](http://fleder44.net/312/notes/16Files/Index.html) website.

I have no idea how to fix this error. The name of my file is correctly written in the `DATASEG` (ending with a zero byte), the file resides in the same folder as my program, and the registers are (as far as I know) filled with the correct data.

A snippet of my file handling code:

```
CODESEG

...

  mov ah, 3Dh
  lea dx, [mapfile]
  mov al, 0
  int 21h

  mov [handle], ax  ; AX currently doesn't contain the handle, but the error code

...

DATASEG
  mapfile db "map.txt", 0
  handle dw ?
  buffer db ?
```

Any idea why this error occurs (and how to fix it)?

Comment: Make sure DS register is correct. There could be a mismatch there.

Answer (score 1):

Some reasons why this may fail:

- Was `DS` setup in your program?
- Is the file in the **current directory**? You don't seem to use a full pathspec. The fact that the file is in the same directory as the program does not imply this. Try writing the full pathspec.
- If you're using an emulator like DOSBox, make sure the directory that has this file is mounted beforehand. Very unlikely since it's in the same directory as the program.